# Merging XML documents with PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have these two xml documents:

### XML 1:

```
<outer>
    <foo>
        <foo-child name="fA" special="true">
            content of fA
        </foo-child>
        <foo-child name="fB">
            content of fB
        </foo-child>
    </foo>
    <bar>
        <bar-child name="bA">
            content of bA
        </bar-child>
        <bar-child name="bB" special="true">
            content of bB
        </bar-child>
    </foo>
</outer>
```

### XML 2:

```
<outer>
    <foo>
        <foo-child name="fA">
            newer and improved content of fA
        </foo-child>
        <foo-child name="fC">
            content of fC
        </foo-child>
    </foo>
    <bar>
        <bar-child name="bA" really-special="true" />
        <bar-child name="bB" special="false">
            Despecialized content of bB
        </bar-child>
    </foo>
</outer>
```

I want to merge them together such that elements from document two override elements with the same `name` attribute in document one. If no attribute or content is present in the second document is present, it is inherited from the first. So:

### Combined

```
<outer>
    <foo>
        <foo-child name="fA" special="true">
            newer and improved content of fA
        </foo-child>
        <foo-child name="fB">
            content of fB
        </foo-child>
        <foo-child name="fC">
            content of fC
        </foo-child>
    </foo>
    <bar>
        <bar-child name="bA" really-special="true">
            content of bA
        </bar-child>
        <bar-child name="bB">
            Despecialized content of bB
        </bar-child>
    </foo>
</outer>
```

My intent is to do this server-side with PHP.

However, i'm unsure whether this is a job for `DomDocument` or SimpleXML. I haven't really used either, and keep thinking "I wish I had jQuery".

Is there a simple solution to this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merging two XML source documents with XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192627/merging-two-xml-source-documents-with-xslt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going with [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) is the right path there and probably easier one. Here is a good tutorial on how to use it:

[Introduction To SimpleXML With PHP](http://phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-To-SimpleXML-With-PHP.html)

Comment: Whats the best way of writing the XML back to a file with SimpleXML?

Comment: The above question is exactly where I am looking for, but I do not think that a link to a general tutorial can mark this question as answered. How did you solve it using SimpleXML?

Answer (score 0):

Link is fine now. I agree with Sarfraz, and this is nice solution to merge XMLs with SImpleXML from comment on [PHP manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php), working also with attributes too:

```
function append_simplexml(&$simplexml_to, &$simplexml_from)
{
    foreach ($simplexml_from->children() as $simplexml_child)
    {
        $simplexml_temp = $simplexml_to->addChild($simplexml_child->getName(), (string) $simplexml_child);
        foreach ($simplexml_child->attributes() as $attr_key => $attr_value)
        {
            $simplexml_temp->addAttribute($attr_key, $attr_value);
        }

        append_simplexml($simplexml_temp, $simplexml_child);
    }
}
```

There also is sample of usage.